# Getting generated image to show on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this link http://weather.msfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/get-goes?satellite=GOES-E%20HURRICANE&lat=14.6&lon=-90.5&zoom=1&info=vis to generate an image, but cannot add that url to an  tag how can I get the generated jpg image to include in my site ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response of that URL, is an HTML file, and `text/html` is the **Internet Media Type** of it, so it can't be used directly inside an `<img />` tag.

This means that either you should include it as an `iframe` in your site (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/hE6AE/1/)), or you should parse the response and find the **true URL** of the image, and use that URL as the source of an `<img />` tag.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `iframe`. Since cross-domain AJAX isn't possible (at least not for HTML), the alternative would be to do server-side parsing of the remote HTML to extract the image URL.

Comment: @PPvG you can use cross-domain Ajax with GET method, but not with POST

Comment: @YaronUliel, cross-domain ajax does not depend on HTTP Verb. What you talk about is called JSONP, and is not AJAX under the hood at all.

Comment: By making a server-side parsing, you mean use a php that gets the image and responds it as Img ?